# Can I always allow an app to make changes?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, software

My MacBook Pro overheats (without this program on) and I am planning on reapplying thermal paste but until then I need this program.

So whenever I log in it shows this prompt which it needs to disable turbo boost:
[image]

So I have to type my password twice when I log in, is there a way I can just allow it to "make changes" without my password?

Comment: You could try and run the app via sudo in terminal. It would run the program with root access, but in order to use sudo, you'd need to enter in your password. This is really only relevant if you turn turbo boost on and off.